# What is the TIME Data Type in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

With Google Analytics API I am getting the value of [ga:avgSessionDuration](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=session&jump=ga_avgsessionduration).

The result is this value: 118.72727272727273

But when I go on the Google Analytics interface I get: 00:01:59

I look at the documentation and it says that [ga:avgSessionDuration](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=session&jump=ga_avgsessionduration) result value is Data Type TIME...

What does that mean? I just cannot find more detail about TIME Data Type.

How do I get 118.72727272 to 00:01:59?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like seconds to me. 118.72 seconds equals 00:01:59.

**Update:** and now that I'm looking at the link you referred to in your question, it specifically says "seconds".

> The average duration of user sessions represented in total seconds.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=session&jump=ga_avgsessionduration

Comment: Do you know if this is applicable across all reports within GA UI as well? It looks like filters, custom alerts, segments all support various formats of the same data type. I wish there was documentation for it as well... Thank you

Comment: Can you give an example?